# Будет ли клик по элементу страницы отображаться в аналитике сайта?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ: C#, Selenium, WebDriver, Chrome

СЦЕНАРИЙ:
    1. Переходим на сайт. (ВКЛАДКА 1 Браузера)
    2. Находим все ссылки на ВКЛАДКЕ 1.
    3. Кликаем по одной ссылке
    4. Ссылка открывается на отдельной вкладке.
    5. Переводим код на новую ВКЛАДКУ N.
    6. Переводим код на ВКЛАДКУ 1.
    7. Повторяем  п.3 - п.6 три раза

В результате получаем браузер с открытыми несколькими вкладками:
    - ВКЛАДКА 1 (исходная страница сайта с которой собираются ссылки и осуществляется переход)
    - ВКЛАДКА 2
    - ВКЛАДКА 3
    - ВКЛАДКА 4

При выполнении п.6 на ВКЛАДКУ 1 переходит только код, а браузер остаётся на последней открытой вкладке см. скрин

Переход по ссылкам будет осуществляться с помощью кода (привожу фрагмент кода)
**КОД**

```
element = Browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a:link"));  
element.Click();
```

**ВОПРОС**
Будут ли переходы по ссылкам сайта восприниматься аналитикой сайта (Гугл аналитик, Яндекс Аналитик или др. средства контроля посещаемости) как переходы выполненные человеком или всё же будут распознаны, что переходы выполняет программа?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS-вставкам, коими являются Google Analytics и пр., не известно, живой человек кликнул или Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае переходы не должны восприниматься как настоящие

1. Если браузер управляется вебрайвером, то в заголовках будет явно прописан "webdriver"
2. Средства аналитики защищены от таких простых методов накрутки

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Nakilon ошибался  в своём ответе?  Цитата: "то в заголовках будет явно прописан "webdriver"" вы предполагаете или утверждаете с уверенностью?